# in django why doesn't my database table get all the info that i entered into the form?

Tags: python, django

in Django  why doesn't my database table get all the info that i entered into the form?
i only get the name and the age when i retrieve the table and the rest not showing?
there is no indentation error i use pycharm
i need to know why when i look at the table phpmyadmin i only see result for the full_name and the age
is there anyway to help is there any kind of certain type of database utf8 or anything else
thanks for help
and if you dont get me well
please contact me on facebook
https://www.facebook.com/7assan3aly/
view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Contact
from django.contrib import messages

def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('full_name') \
                 and request.POST.get('email') \
                 and request.POST.get('mobile_number') \
                 and request.POST.get('whatsapp') \
                 and request.POST.get('xray_image') \
                 and request.POST.get('message'):
            savored = Contact()
            savored.full_name = request.POST.get('full_name')
            savored.age = request.POST.get('age')
            savored.email = request.POST.get('email')
            savored.mobile_number = request.POST.get('mobile_number')
            savored.whatsapp = request.POST.get('whatsapp')
            savored.xray_image = request.POST.get('xray_image')
            savored.message = request.POST.get('message')
            savored.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Done')
            return render(request, 'contact.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'contact.html')
===========model.py=============
from django.db import models


class Contact(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    # age = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=33)
    whatsapp = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    xray_image = models.CharField(max_length=301)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "contacts"
```

Comment: Use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

Answer (score 0):

we as a coder, sould try to write codes as less as possible!

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Contact
from django.contrib import messages

def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        savored = Contact(
        full_name = request.POST.get('full_name', None)
        age = request.POST.get('age', None)
        email = request.POST.get('email', None)
        mobile_number = request.POST.get('mobile_number', None)
        whatsapp = request.POST.get('whatsapp', None)
        xray_image = request.POST.get('xray_image', None)
        message = request.POST.get('message' ,None)
        )
        for field in Contact._meta.fields:
            if field.isnull: # so the instance has at least one field with null value
                 break
        else:
             savored.save()
             messages.success(request, 'Done')
             return render(request, 'contact.html')
        return render(request, 'contact.html')`
```

if any filed of the has no data within it, so it would be considered as None.

Comment: 1st of thank you too much, but i still get the same result

Comment: ok, it seems you need to define your model in a way which evry filed of that model won't accept`null` and then use a `forms.ModelForm` so user shall fill the form.